# How do I render X <option>s in a <select>using jQuery.tmpl?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I'm inserting rows in a `<table>` that are bound to a JSON object.  A cell in the table contains a `<select>` that needs to contain the number of objects, so 7 objects would produce 7 `<option>`s, 1-7.

Can this be done in the template definition?

Edit: I've added sample data and markup.  From this data, I would want to add 3 `<option>`s (1-3) to the DisplayOrder `<select>` and have the appropriate `<option>` selected for each `<select>`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4SxTS/

```
var data = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "DisplayOrder": 1,
    "LabelText": "Unit On-Line Status:"},
{
    "Id": 2,
    "DisplayOrder": 2,
    "LabelText": "AGC Pct:"},
{
    "Id": 3,
    "DisplayOrder": 3,
    "LabelText": "Main Steam Heat Rate
}];

<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead><tr><th>Display Order</th><th>Label Text</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script id="attributeTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td><select name="DisplayOrder"></select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="LabelText" value="${LabelText}" /></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: any chance you could give some sample html that the script should produce?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is rearranging your data possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean without some sample data and markup, but I think the main part of your question deals with looping through numbers and rendering an `option` tag for each number. You could do this by creating an array containing "N" elements and then using `{{each}}`, but I think that using a custom template tag works well here:

1. Define a `{{for}}` tag that iterates through numbers 0 to n:

   ```
   $.extend(jQuery.tmpl.tag, {
       'for': {
           open: "for(var $i = 0; $i < $1; $i++) {",
           close: "}"
       }
   });
   ```
2. Use the new tag in a template:

   ```
   <script type="text/html" id="row-tmpl">
       {{each Rows}}
       <tr>
           <td>${Title}</td>
           <td>${Description}</td>
           <td>
               <select>
                   {{for $data.TotalObjects}}
                   <option>${$i}</option>
                   {{/for}}
               </select>
           </td>
       </tr>
       {{/each}}
   </script>
   ```

   Called with:

   ```
   var rows = {
       TotalObjects: 5,
       Rows: [{
           Title: 'Test Row',
           Description: 'Test Row Description'
       },
       {
           Title: 'Another Row',
           Description: 'Another Row Description'
       }]
   };
   ```

Best demonstrated in a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xgE3Y/

Your situation might be even simpler, but my answer should enable you to at least use a simple `for` loop in a template and act on each iteration's value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$(function () {

        var thisSelectObjects = 8;
        var thatSelectObjects = 2;


        $.fn.setOptions = function (options) {

            var settings = {
                'selectNum': 1
            };

            return this.each(function () {
                if (options) {
                    $.extend(settings, options);
                }
                for (i = 0; i < settings.selectNum; i++) {
                    $(this).append('<option>' + i + '<option/>');
                }
            });
        };



        $('#thisSelect').setOptions({ 'selectNum': thisSelectObjects });
        $('#thatSelect').setOptions({ 'selectNum': thatSelectObjects });

    });
```

Html:

```
    <body>
    <select id='thisSelect'></select>
    <select id='thatSelect'></select>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm looking for something that uses the jQuery.tmpl framework.

Comment: oops sorry, i tool that literally. like make a templated piece of code